# PptxGenJS - Use addSlidesForTable() to insert table in a existing slide

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, pptxgenjs

I need to have 3 columns in a slide with table in the middle column. I have an HTML table to populate the table and hoping to use `addSlidesForTable()` method to do this.
However `addSlidesForTable()` is creating a new slide and inserting table in that slide. 
Is there any way to convert HTML table to ppt in my existing table (e.g. in the middle column)

Thanks